# Is there a way to make some application have different resolution on a Retina Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, display

I use "Best for Retina display" in my settings. It's suitable for my eyes:)

But I'd like to get more spaces in some applications by using the highest resolution. So is there a way to do so?

Comment: As in have different applications running at different resolutions at the same time?

Comment: @Pena Yes, that's it! Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, so far as I know, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The OS doesn't have any sort of procedure to tell app A to use one screen size and app B another.

Unless the apps you use have a preference to change layout, icon size or other aspects of layout and zoom (like a spreadsheet tool can zoom in and out regardless of the overall resolution), you'll have to pick the best resolution and then change it up as needed based on your workflow.